# Define map palette using variable from FeatureCollection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to plot the ESA CCI land cover map using the palette that they define in their .csv download. I managed to import this palette into GEE by saving it as a shapefile with a dummy geometry (using `R`), which I'm hoping I've made publicly available [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/rasenior/cci_landcover_legend).

I'm testing it out by changing the palette in GEE's [Image Visualization tutorial](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_visualization) (for a different land cover dataset, but I'll stick with it for simplicity). So, first, I load the MODIS land cover:

```
// Load 2012 MODIS land cover and select the IGBP classification.
var cover = ee.Image('MODIS/051/MCD12Q1/2012_01_01')
  .select('Land_Cover_Type_1');
```

Then I define my alternative palette:

```
// Load alternative colour palette
var cciPalette = 
  ee.List(
  ee.FeatureCollection('users/rasenior/cci_landcover_legend')
 .aggregate_array('hex'));

// Remove '#' symbol and make lower case
var replace = function(name){
  return (ee.String(name).replace('#', '').toLowerCase());
}; 
var cciPalette2 = cciPalette.map(replace);
print(cciPalette2);
```

The console tells me that `cciPalette2` is a list, and everything looks good. It looks just like the `igbpPalette` from the tutorial (a longer list because CCI have more land cover categories). But when I sub `cciPalette2` in for `igbpPalette`:

```
Map.setCenter(-99.229, 40.413, 5);
Map.addLayer(cover,
             {min: 0, max: 17, palette: cciPalette2},
             'CCI classification');
```

I get the error:

```
CCI classification: Layer error: Image.visualize: Expected a string or list of strings for field 'palette'.
```

But `cciPalette2` is a list of strings, no? What am I doing wrong? I'm a total GEE and `javascript` novice so I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Full code here:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/be1102eda2fb41584e9be3697f42b48e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate layer you need to have a palette on the client side that gets sent to GEE to generate the map. Since you are generating palette based on aggregating a property in a feature collection, the **ccgiPalette2** is neither a string nor a list of strings but a computed object type instead. You can use the **evaluate** or **getInfo** function to address this.

```
var cciPalette2 = cciPalette.map(replace).getInfo();
```

Would be the simplest solution, and your script will work without further changes but since **getInfo** is deprecated i recommend using **evaluate** function instead which works by setting up a callback function.

```
cciPalette.map(replace).evaluate(function(cciPalette2){
  // Map again
  Map.setCenter(-99.229, 40.413, 5);
  Map.addLayer(cover,
               {min: 0, max: 17, palette: cciPalette2},
               'CCI classification');
});
```

The good thing about **evaluate** is that it does not freeze the UI while the data is being fetched.